# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'switchClass'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an easter egg for my website. I have used this code on a different project before, the only difference is the classnames that are being switched. When entering `secret1` as input, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'switchClass'` in the console. Here is my script:

```
var secret1 = "70767380"; //flip
var secret2 = "857870767380"; //unflip
var input = "";
var timer;
var mode = false;

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    input += e.which;    

    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() { input = ""; }, 1000);

    check_input();
});

function check_input() {
    if(input === secret1) {
        $( ".desktop_wrapper" ).switchClass( "desktop_wrapper", "desktop_wrapper_flip", 1000 );        
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() { $('#info').html('Keystroke: ' + input); }, 100);
});
```

And my CSS:

```
.desktop_wrapper
    {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        /*Høyde kun for å illustrere scrolling*/
        height: 2000px;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 1024px;

        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;

        box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 30px #b5b5b5, 0px 0px 10px 2px #000000;
    }

    .desktop_wrapper_flip
    {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: “FlipH”;
    }
```

Comment: The error message is clear: there's no method named "switchClass" on a jQuery object. You may be thinking of "toggleClass".

Comment: `switchClass()` is a method from **jQuery UI**. Have you included it on the page?

Comment: Thank you for quick answers :) Tried adding the correct jQuery lib, but that didnt work. Changed it to toggleClass() and it now works! Kudos.